# bash set -e not work on if statement call function

Tags: bash

I've tested on bash version 4.1.2 and 4.4.2.0.
In the following code, the last i value will be 4.
Why the 'false' command not stopped when f4() was called in 'if' statement?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

i=0
f4() {
  i=$((i+1))
  echo "in f4 before false, i=$i"
  false
  i=$((i+2))
  echo "in f4 after false, i=$i"
}
if f4 ; then
  echo "f4 pass, i=$i"
fi
f4
```

The output of this script

```
+ i=0
+ f4
+ i=1
+ echo 'in f4 before false, i=1'
in f4 before false, i=1
+ false
+ i=3
+ echo 'in f4 after false, i=3'
in f4 after false, i=3
+ echo 'f4 pass, i=3'
f4 pass, i=3
+ f4
+ i=4
+ echo 'in f4 before false, i=4'
in f4 before false, i=4
+ false
```

What I expect is

```
+ i=0
+ f4
+ i=1
+ echo 'in f4 before false, i=1'
in f4 before false, i=1
+ false
+ f4
+ i=2
+ echo 'in f4 before false, i=2'
in f4 before false, i=2
+ false
```

So, this behavior means if we write a function, The 'set -e' may change its behavior by different method to call the function.

Comment: It's working perfectly. The problem is that `set -e` is not the magic bullet that online guides claim it to be. See [this page](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for more details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but `false` in `f4()` doesn't cause `f4()` to return with a non-zero value, if you want a condition to do that, then replace `false` with some condition and a return statement.

Comment: even if you "return" false as suggested by @DavidC.Rankin , a non-zero return value **wrapped** in `if` will not cause the script to exit. if you want to forcibly exit from inside `f4()` use `return <non zero int>` and handle it in the `else/elif` block. check @thatotherguy's linked resource for a more in-depth explanation

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This simplified script, just demostrate, if use the different call, the behavior will be different by set -e effect.   Seems no easy way to set option to enable the same behavior.

Comment: @DanielYCLin : The whole point of `if` is to test whether a command returns a non-zero exit code, and take appropriate actions accordingly. Aborting the script in such a case would make the whole `if` construct meaningless. The same applies to `while`. For the same reason, when you do a `X && Y` and `X || Y`, the script is not aborted if `X` returns non-zero exit code.